# How to make an SQL query with codeigniter framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, mariadb

How to make this query with codeigniter?

```
SELECT `nome_paciente` 
FROM `cronograma_preventivo` 
JOIN `paciente` 
ON `cronograma_preventivo`.`id_paciente` = `paciente`.`id_paciente` 
WHERE `mes` = '2016-09-01' 
AND `kit_higiene` + `raspagem` + `atendimento` + "aplicacao_fluor" + "evidenciacao_placa" + "polimento_protese" != 0
GROUP BY `nome_paciente`
```

I tried this:

```
  $this->db->join('paciente', 'cronograma_preventivo.id_paciente = paciente.id_paciente');
  $this->db->select('nome_paciente');
  $this->db->where('mes', date('Y-m-01',strtotime("NOW")));
  $this->db->where("(kit_higiene+raspagem+atendimento+aplicacao_fluor+evidenciacao_placa+polimento_protese)>=0");
  $this->db->group_by('nome_paciente');
```

But this doesn't work :(

Comment: "not work" doesn't convey any real information about the behavior you are observing. Is it returning an error message? or returning unexpected resultset? The SQL query presented includes double quotes... are those supposed to be enclosing column references, or are those supposed to be string literals? Also, the column references aren't qualified, and we can't tell which table contains which columes, i.e. `\`mes\``.

Comment: I don't understand what `+"aplicacao_fluor"+"evidenciacao_placa"+"polimento_protese"` is supposed to do

Comment: Plus you have a GROUP BY clause but no aggregating functions - which makes very little sense

Comment: In the query builder code, I don't see where `cronograma_preventivo` is referenced as a row source. (I'm not seeing the equivalent of `FROM cronograma_preventio`). @Strawberry: the GROUP BY includes all of the expressions in the SELECT list, so it's going to remove duplicates, equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT`. (I still don't know what behavior OP is observing, or what OP is trying to achieve. And like you, I don't know if `sql_mode` includes `ANSI_QUOTES`. So are those double quotes are meant to enclose string literals, or are they meant to enclose column references?)

Comment: this makes a sum of column values, I need to return the "nome_paciente" where the sum of columns is different from 0.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: <opinion>3rd party software gets in the way.</opinion>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like a line like this is missing from the query builder code:

```
 $this->db->from('cronograma_preventivo')
```

And it seems to me like the

```
 $this->db->select()
```

should come *first*, before the `db->from`, which should be before the `db->join`.

I'm just guessing. I don't do codeigniter Query Builder. I'm not familiar with the requirements for ordering the methods. I'm much more comfortable crafting SQL that needs to be submitted to the database. And I much prefer to *qualify* all column references, for one, as a benefit future readers who may not be as familiar with the database schema, which columns come from which tables, and two, to prevent my SQL from breaking with an "ambiguous column" reference when a column with the same name is added to another table.

```
  SELECT p.nome_paciente
    FROM cronograma_preventivo r
    JOIN paciente p
      ON p.id_paciente = r.id_paciente
   WHERE r.mes = '2016-09-01'
     AND ( r.kit_higiene 
         + r.raspagem
         + r.atendimento
         + r.aplicacao_fluor
         + r.evidenciacao_placa
         + r.polimento_protese
         ) != 0
   GROUP BY p.nome_paciente
```

And if I had to convert that to CodeIgniter QueryBuilder, I would try something like this:

```
  $this->db->select('p.nome_paciente');
  $this->db->from('cronograma_preventivo r');
  $this->db->join('paciente p','p.id_paciente = r.id_paciente');
  $this->db->where('r.mes','2016-09-01');
  $this->db->where('( r.kit_higiene
         + r.raspagem
         + r.atendimento
         + r.aplicacao_fluor
         + r.evidenciacao_placa
         + r.polimento_protese
         ) != 0');
  $this->db->group_by('p.nome_paciente');
```

And if I observed that this did "not work", and I posted a question on StackOverflow, I would include some information about the actual behavior I was observing, especially any *error messages* that are returned.

If I was getting an unexpected resultset, then I would take a look at the SQL statement that CodeIgniter was generating, and compare it to the query that I want constructed, and go from there.